# Combining output rows by date

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a following problem with PL/SQL..

I need to retrieve data from the table for various parameters, for the certain time period, but on the output I have duplicates for dates providing me an output for each column, but not combining them together. Could I please borrow your geniuses for this issue?

Here is my code (part of it, as it repeats the same for other parameters I need to deliver):

```
select /*+FULL(k)*/ k.date_n,

 SUM(decode(bucket_flag_n,
        '1',
        (DECODE(type_s,
                    'MOC',
                    decode(on_off_net_s, 'On net', duration_sum),
                    'MOC_4',
                    decode(on_off_net_s, 'On net', duration_sum),
                    'MOC CF_4',
                    decode(on_off_net_s, 'On net', duration_sum),0)))) test1,

 SUM(decode(bucket_flag_n, 
         '0',
         (DECODE(type_s, 
                     'MOC',
                     decode(on_off_net_s, 'Off net', duration_sum),
                     'MOC_4', 
                     decode(on_off_net_s, 'Off net', duration_sum), 
                     'MOC CF_4', 
                     decode(on_off_net_s, 'Off net', duration_sum),0)))) test2

  from (select /*+FULL(a)*/
         a.d_timestamp date_n,
         a.service_s type_s,
         a.country_s,
         a.on_off_net_s,
         a.bucket_flag_n,
         round(SUM(a.duration_n / 60)) duration_sum, --minutes rounded
         SUM(a.count_n) sms_count, -- sms count
         round(SUM(a.volume_n / 1024 / 1024)) volume_sum -- volume mb rounded

          from database a, database2 b

         where a.country_s = 'Country'
           and a.free_of_charge_flag_n = '1'
           and a.d_timestamp between b.date_from and b.date_to
         group by a.d_timestamp,
                  a.service_s,
                  a.country_s,
                  a.on_off_net_s,
                  a.bucket_flag_n) k

 group by k.date_n, bucket_flag_n
 order by 1
```

Here is what I gt on the output:

[image: http://imgur.com/z4DGdtO]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us what you have in the output

Comment: was struggling adding a pic( added link to the post)

Answer (score 0):

Your `group by` clause is:

```
group by k.date_n, bucket_flag_n
```

If you only want one row per date, then change it to:

```
group by k.date_n
```

I would also suggest that you learn modern `join` syntax ("never use commas in the `from` clause") and replace `decode()` with `case`.  However, those are syntactic conventions and don't affect the results from the query.

Comment: Thank you.. It is so silly right now. Here I have copied my latest version of it, where I have SUM(decode..), but before I had SUM(decode...SUM(decode) and it did not want to work without bucket_flag_n in group by

Answer (score 0):

There's several strange things going on here.
First off, you say:

> Here is my code (part of it, as it repeats the same for other
> parameters I need to deliver):

Which implies that all aggregate, non-grouped columns have the `DECODE(...)` containing `'MOC'`, `'MOC_4'`, and `'MOC CF_4'` - if so, you can actually make those part of the `WHERE` clause, which may actually speed up your query (Assuming `service_s` has other codes not used in the query, and relevant indices).

The next thing is, you're using an inclusive upper-bound (`<=`, found in `BETWEEN`) with what appears to be a timestamp.  [This will give you wrong results](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - often, midnight of the next day is incorrectly included, although there are other possibilities too.  When dealing with positive, contiguous-range types, you **must** use an exclusive upper-bound (`<`), or suffer the consequences: this is an inherent property of *representation of numbers*, and has nothing to do with implementation in a computer, or specific applications.  (I also find the names somewhat poor, especially as `d_timestamp` doesn't really tell me anything about what it represents)

Math, and rounding issues:
Assuming `duration_n`, `count_n`, and `volumn_n` (...what does `_n` stand for?  Why the suffix?) are `INTEGER` types, `ROUND(...)` is unnecessary, as all math performed will be integer-based, and return non-fractional amounts in the first place.  The commutative property of addition can *potentially* be exploited - you can rewrite `SUM(a.duration_n / 60)` as `SUM(a.duration_n) / 60` (performance gains, if any, would be low) - however if the given column is an `INTEGER` type you will get **different** results (which is correct is up to you - actually, given computer limitations it gives different answers no matter what the type is, but would be most pronounced with an integral type).

---

Given some of the mentioned assumptions (namely, that all aggregate columns have the same `DECODE(..)`, we can simplify the query somewhat:

```
SELECT A.d_timestamp AS date_n,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.bucket_flag_n = '1' AND A.on_off_net_s = 'On net' 
                THEN A.duration_n END) / 60 AS test1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.bucket_flag_n = '0' AND A.on_off_net_s = 'Off net' 
                THEN A.duration_n END) / 60 AS test2
FROM Database A
JOIN Database2 B
  ON A.d_timestamp >= B.date_from
     AND A.d_timestamp < B.date_to
WHERE A.country_s = 'Country'
      AND A.free_of_charge_flag_n = '1'
      AND A.service_s IN ('MOC', 'MOC_4', 'MOC CF_4')
      AND ((bucket_flag_n = '1' AND on_off_net_s = 'On net')
           OR (bucket_flag_n = '0' AND on_off_net_s = 'Off net'))
GROUP BY A.d_timestamp
ORDER BY A.d_timestamp
```

... adding the remaining aggregate columns is left as an exercise to the reader.
A couple of notes:  If the relationship between `bucket_flag_n` and `on_off_net_s` is as indicated in *all* cases, you can actually remove the conditions from the `WHERE` clause.  If you have other that you're bucketing you may have to anyways.  I'm also suspicious of the usefulness of grouping by something that claims to be a *timestamp*, as these are usually too high resolution for useful groups in aggregation (ie - each value tends to be on its own line).  If the value is a date you have a different problem...